# Visual Studio perpetually reinstalls Cloud SDK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I have Visual Studio installed on Manjaro. After the last system update, Visual Studio stopped working with the Cloud Code extension.  It perpetually installs and uninstalls the extension and throws the next error message:

> Cloud SDK was installed but was found to be invalid or corrupted so it was removed. Attempting to reinstall. Managed dependencies will be unavailable during this process. (install attempt 1)

I tried to reinstall the SDK, the extension, and the Visual Studio. Nothing changes at all.

Comment: Can you try reinstalling by following the steps mentioned in [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install)?

Comment: @BadalaPrashanth, yes I tried to reinstall both ways: via package manager and following steps from the official docs. All the time the same issue. I ended up using Cloud SDK in console.

Visual Studio still doesn't want to recognize the installation and perpetually tries to reinstall it in ~/.cache/cloud-code/installer/google-cloud-sdk folder and overrides PATH variable..

Comment: What worked for me was to uninstall cloud code, quit vscode, kill docker in terminal, and then reinstall cloud code.

Comment: @AntoineRNT this it's happening to me, and when I open more than one instance of code at the same time, my PC freeze. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install Cloud Code without any any issues, using the below steps as provided [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode&ssr=false#overview). This includes the dependencies like Cloud SDK, kubectl etc.

> Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press enter.
>
> ext install GoogleCloudTools.cloudcode

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me and would take lots of resources to start each vscode window. My best solution was to use locally installed dependencies by setting the `cloudcode.autoDependencies` to `off`. It's worked like a charm since then.

Reference and needed dependencies: https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/install#custom_versions_of_dependencies